# Matching characters in a string based on its position

Tags: regex

I'm curious if it is possible to get some help building a regEx that can check for matches of letter placement against incoming strings. For instance, lets say I had 'f' in the first character, 'o' in the second and so on... then validate that as I loop strings.

Hopefully this makes sense! Please let me know if you need any more details! Thanks!

ps. This is all in plain ol' ASCII.

---

Edit:

To be more clear about the character position matching, for instance, if I had a pattern of:

```
- e - p
```

I'd like to be able to have the string of 'derp' match as true (since it's hitting the second and fourth characters).

Comment: @C2H5OH You're correct about that as it totally matches, but not in terms of when character spacing comes into play. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any word character

*e?p -> **\w+e\wp**

or any aplha

*e?p -> **[a-z]+e[a-z]p**

*and for 4 characters*

any word character

?e?p -> **\we\wp**

or any aplha

?e?p -> **[a-z]e[a-z]p**

**UPDATE**

Use the above patterns to create more specific matches where * and ? are dos like.
For example:

mis?i?n -> **mis[a-z]i[a-z]n**

*i?n -> **[a-z]+i[a-z]n**

The first one will match "mission" and the second one will match "mission" and "passion" and "fashion"...

Comment: Thank you, so far so good! How would this type of regEx (if possible) extend to longer strings... for instance, if I had a longer string to match against words, like: 'mis-i-n' (which should match the string 'mission'). Sorry for my probably delusional-sounding requests. :)

Comment: Thanks! I slapped a ^ on the front of my pattern and that seemed to do exactly the trick. Again, thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

Change your hyphens to dots:

```
^.e.p$
```

A dot means match any character apart from new line.

Answer (score 0):

this is possibly the fifth easiest regex to construct.  If you want to match a specific string in positions 0 through 4 (say) of an input string and the letters you want to match are 'abcde', then the following regex does the trick:

```
/^(abcde)/
```